# workaround for this module?

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, pwntools

Im trying to install pwntools on OSX but theres a little bump in the installation process, for some reason, there is this module called "unicorn" that uses a setup.py which is deprecated, is there a work around for this?

```bash
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [4 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      Building C extensions
      error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/6p/l9f35jf50_v8j2yq_1l5h62w0000gp/T/pip-install-fbw0k5so/unicorn_8ea27fd7a2de4d1ea34a12cce6c691c5/../../include/unicorn'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for unicorn
  Running setup.py clean for unicorn
Failed to build unicorn
Installing collected packages: unicorn, sortedcontainers, pyserial, pyelftools, urllib3, ropgadget, python-dateutil, pysocks, pyparsing, pygments, pycparser, psutil, plumbum, pathlib2, MarkupSafe, intervaltree, idna, charset-normalizer, certifi, bcrypt, rpyc, requests, packaging, mako, colored-traceback, cffi, pynacl, cryptography, paramiko, pwntools
  Running setup.py install for unicorn ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for unicorn did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      running install
      /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      Building C extensions
      error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/6p/l9f35jf50_v8j2yq_1l5h62w0000gp/T/pip-install-fbw0k5so/unicorn_8ea27fd7a2de4d1ea34a12cce6c691c5/../../include/unicorn'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> unicorn

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: Try to install it from a wheel.

Comment: @tripleee it looks like there's only a Mac wheel for x86_64. If OP has an M1 chip, they'll need to build from source.

Comment: https://github.com/unicorn-engine/unicorn/issues/1541 , https://github.com/unicorn-engine/unicorn/issues/1707